# How to fill a color in ion-icon ios-thumbs-up-outline

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionicons

I am using ion-icon as

**.html**

```
<ion-icon name="ios-thumbs-up-outline" [style.color]="'#EF3B51'"></ion-icon>
```

When I do this the icon's outline changes to red color but I want to fill red color in the empty space inside the icon.

You can see the image below:

[image]

Comment: is there a reason for not using the solid thumb icon v/s outlined one, and adding color red style to it?

Comment: you may try this to edit vector fill outlined icons https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/manipulating-svg-icons-with-simple-css--webdesign-15694

Comment: @SunilKumar Yes If I dont click on like button then It should look similar to the ios-thumbs-up-outline and If I use md-thumbs-up then I had to make similar to ios-thumbs-up-outline using the same questions.

Comment: I m not using svgs here, if would appreciate if i would be done using ion-icons

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this will resolve the issue

`<ion-icon name="ios-thumbs-up" [style.color]="'#EF3B51'"></ion-icon>`

what ever available in the [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/ionicons/) is what you can use if you need anything else you need to use image

Comment: How would you do this with CSS4 variables?

Comment: You can just use normal CSS like `style="color: #EF3B51"` instead as well.